# Prove that there are $c,d$ with $a<c<d<b$ and $f(c)<f(a)$ as well as $f(d)<f(b)$

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let f be a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ and $f’(a)<0<f’(b)$
Prove that there are $c,d$ with $a<c<d<b$ and $f(c)<f(a)$ as well as $f(d)<f(b)$

I used the MVT on f on $(a,c)$ and $(d,b)$ respectively and I got:
$∃ α ∈ (a,c) : f’(α) = f(a) - f(c) / a - c$

$∃ β ∈ (d,b) : f’(β) = f(d) - f(b) / d - b$

so since $a-c<0$ and $d-b<0$
I only need to show that $f’(α)<0$ and $f’(β)>0$

Answer (score 0):

I'll prove that $\exists c\in(a,e):f(c)<f(a)$ with $e=(a+b)/2.$ Using $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\downarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ and the definition of the limit, we get that
\begin{align*}
\exists\delta>0:0<x-a<\delta&\Rightarrow\left\lvert\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)\right\rvert<-f'(a)/2,\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a)<-f'(a)/2,\\
&\Rightarrow\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<f'(a)/2<0.
\end{align*}
Using $x-a>0,$ we get that $f(x)-f(a)<0.$ Let $c=a+\min(\delta,e-a)/2.$ Then, because $0<\min(\delta,e-a)/2<\delta,e-a,$ we have that $0<c-a<\delta$ and $c\in(a,e).$

Likewise, $\exists d\in(e,b):f(d)<f(b).$ Notice that $c<e<d.$